# ListView not clickable

Tags: android

I have an android activity that has a list view and in each list item there is a button. I want the button and the list item to be clickable but only the button is clickable and the textview on the list item is not clickable. Any idea how could this work ?. Thank you

Comment: `android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to buttons in xml

Comment: did you try does it work?

Comment: Have you tried putting the event handler inside list adapter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this .. add  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the relativelayout in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

I Thing u r Using Coustem List View in Android so u create Buttan And TextView Object in Coustem Adopter View 
      Add The OnClickListner In Buttan or TextView in Coustem Adopter

```
buttan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

        }
    });
 textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

        }
    });
```

if U want to click perticuller Buttan or TextView so Use

```
if(position==0)
{
 click Event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the options:

If you implementet the TextView via XML-Layout use this:

```
<TextView
  //layout and stuff
  android:clickable = "true"
  android:onClick = "you method name" />
```

if you implemented it during runtime,

use

```
  TextView tv = new TextView.this
  tv.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before, i don't know why this is happening but i made an onclick event on the layout that holds all the list item layout instead of onitemclick event and it works for me

Comment: but I want to have an action performed when clicking on each item  on the list

Comment: i have a button in the list and its onclick event works fine too